# Why is the size of GMVault backup significantly smaller than size of gmail storage?

Tags: backup, sync, gmail

I just discovered GMVault and did a sync with my Gmail account.  I am pleased by the tool, but I am curious to know the answer to the title of this question.

After doing a `gmvault sync -t full --emails-only` the size of the backup on my hard drive is 3.6GB.  However, this Gmail account reports 5.2GB of current storage used.

I know the above command is `--emails-only` but I have no chats in Gmail.  **Any idea why the size discrepancy?**  I'm concerned I might somehow be missing some data.

One possible explanation is that there may be certain aspects of Gmail that GMVault does not pick up (e.g. certain attachments).  Another is that the file structures of GMVault v Gmail are sufficiently different, although if this were the case I would expect that Gmail would be pretty well-optimized for space.

Comment: music2myear and DavidPostill please remove the "hold" - I am asking a very specific, answerable question.  There were questioning sentences in my original post (I have since re-worded them), but they were not "multiple distinct" questions, rather all related to the thrust of the post.  Thanks!

Comment: Questions about Google serviced are not within scope

Comment: The [\[gmail\]](https://superuser.com/tags/gmail/info) tag wiki says that questions about Gmail are on topic here if they involve working with a desktop client. This seems to qualify.

Comment: If anyone has a suggested alternative forum for me to post this in, please let me know...

Comment: Is your local backup copy compressed at all? Or did you use GMVault's `--no-compression` option? I'm assuming Gmail only reports the storage size used in uncompressed data, but I'm positive they use some compression on their own servers, but google doesn't want to reveal much about gmail's inner workings. And is this a new / clean Gmvault-db?

Comment: @Xen2050 - an excellent point about compression, and I suspect you are correct.  I am new to Gmvault (so it's a clean gmvault-db), and I hadn't noticed that it is indeed compressed.  A very simple answer.  If you post it I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, I can't answer yet since it's still on hold for now. A clean database shouldn't have any wasted space or "trash" yet to be deleted, so it's likely the compression. Could confirm by creating another new database without compression (using `--no-compression`)... but don't bother re-downloading your 3-5GB just for a test, try with a smaller account, or I'll try myself if I can get it installed (no Debian or Ubuntu package, and [it looks non-trivial to install on MX-Linux](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=42829))